# Hide percentage column in flextable in R?

Tags: r, flextable

I have a simple table that I want to produce and only show counts, no percentages which is what flextable defaults to. I can't find a similar question on here or while reading through the package documentation.

```
new_data <- df %>% 
  group_by(var1, var2) %>% 
  select(var1, var2) %>% 
  tabyl(var2) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  print()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `flextable`. It's `janitor::tably` which adds the percentage column which is then displayed in your `flextable`. If you don't want percentages you could use `dplyr::count` instead to create your frequency table.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`.

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  flextable()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With your code:
Remove the column with `select`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(flextable

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  select(cyl, am) %>% 
  tabyl(am) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  select(-percent) %>% 
  flextable()
```

[image]